# java, xsd & marshalling: jre bug, my fault or xsd issues?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am running into a problem while **marshalling** a JAXB model tree to a xml file.

I created those model classes using **xjc**. **I cannot modify these xml schemas** - they are defined externally (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131730/what-causes-saxexception2-instance-of-com-foo-bar-is-substituting-java-lang) question which lacks for answers).

The xml schema files seems to be valid according xjc (and other xml tools).
I am asking whether

- this is a java/jre bug  *or*
- I am doing something wrong  *or*
- if the schema files are somewhat errornous

and how to resolve this issue.

The exception which I get is:

```
com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: "com.mypackage.A" is substituting "com.mypackage.BaseType", but "com.mypackage.A" is bound to an anonymous type.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:652)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:54)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:61)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:54)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:61)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
```

(java 7 update 45)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post a small sample which actually produces that outcome - it is hard to diagnose the reason only on the stack-trace. Have you already tried different JVM versions - even within the same master-version?

Comment: @RomanVottner You're right, but unfortunately, I'm not allowed to publish these XSDs and the corresponding code. But maybe I can try to make a minimalistic example which does not use the actual files.

Comment: Unless you provide a sample nobody can help you.

Comment: Does your schema use inheritance or declare a `complexType` within an `element`?  JAXB can have problems with both, but you might be able to work around it using binding customizations.  JAXB seems to be playing dumb about substitution groups.

Comment: @LeosLiterak - I was able to recreate example code based on his exception:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23093089/383861

Answer (score 13):

### TL;DR

> java, xsd & marshalling: jre bug, my fault or xsd issues?

It's your fault :).  Continue reading for the reason why.

---

### Java Model

Below is a Java model that is based on the one hinted at in your question that can be used to produce the same exception that you are seeing.

**Root**

Below is a root object that has one property.  The type of that property has two subclasses.  One of the subclasses (`B`) corresponds to a named type, and the other (`A`) to an anonymous type.

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private BaseType baseType;

    public BaseType getBaseType() {
        return baseType;
    }

    public void setBaseType(BaseType baseType) {
        this.baseType = baseType;
    }

}
```

**BaseType**

This is the super class.  It has two subclasses: `A` and `B`.

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({A.class, B.class})
public class BaseType {

}
```

**A**

The `A` class corresponds to an anonymous complex type.  An anonymous type is represented with the `@XmlType(name="")` annotation.

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name="")
public class A extends BaseType {

}
```

**B**

The `B` class corresponds to the named complex type `b`.  The default is the same as having `@XmlType(name="b")`.

```
package com.mypackage;

public class B extends BaseType {

}
```

### Demo Code - That Reproduces Error

**Demo**

When the `baseType` property on the `Root` class is one of the subclasses then the `xsi:type` attribute is added to qualify the element (similar to a cast in Java).  The instance is required to correspond to a named complex type.  In this case `A` does not.

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        BaseType baseType = new A(); // Invalid Value
        root.setBaseType(baseType);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Exception**

This results in the following exception.  As stated by the exception `A` is not a valid substitute for `BaseType` because it corresponds to an anonymous complex type, since since it corresponds to an anonymous type it doesn't have the necessary value for the `xsi:type` attribute.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: Instance of "com.mypackage.A" is substituting "com.mypackage.BaseType", but "com.mypackage.A" is bound to an anonymous type.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at com.mypackage.Demo.main(Demo.java:16)
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: Instance of "com.mypackage.A" is substituting "com.mypackage.BaseType", but "com.mypackage.A" is bound to an anonymous type.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:652)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    ... 3 more
```

### Demo Code - That Works

**Demo**

If instead of `A` you specified the other subclass `B` which corresponds to a named complex type.

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        BaseType baseType = new B(); // Valid Value
        root.setBaseType(baseType);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Then you will see everything works as expected an the type name is included when the `baseType` property is marshalled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <baseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b"/>
</root>
```